# Repeating Information in a Web Form - Asp.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am building an employment application form that submits data to a database for my business.

In creating this form, one of the things that captured my attention is that when I created the section for employment history, I thought to myself that most applicants are going to have a variety of information to put in here, and making a required set of 3 past employers is far to rigid for the target prospect base. Some may have just 1 prior job, others may have 10 or more. Plus, making a large amount of fields for this information not only looks bad to the eye, but it is also is a bad practice in the world of database development. SO...

What I would like to do, is something similar as I have done in an Access Database is the theory behind a Subform, where when a user begins to add input data, the form replicates itself making another set of datafields available for as many times as the user needs. This way, only data is being stored - not empty space.

While this is rather a straightforward practice in Microsoft Access, I have discovered that Asp.Net web forms and SQL handle this process in an entirely different manner to accomplish the same goal.

I have done some research on this topic and have discovered that there are many ways to go about this, and most things I found are very vague as to how to go about this. So, I reach out to you.

How would I add a set of repeating fields to handle input of prior work experience? For simplicity sake, lets say we have three fields: Employer, Supervisor, and Job. Lets also assume that the addition of these three fields would take place after the user clicks and add button. What would I need to do to in order to get those three fields to repeat as many times as necessary on my asp.net web form?

Comment: What does your data model look like? do you have a record in a separate table for each employment history? Is the main application record created upfront or once the application is completed? These factors will greatly influence how you implement the problem.

Answer (score 1):

There a lots of options for repeating information in an ASP.NET page, here is an article that goes over a few of them:

[Data Repeater Controls in ASP.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163780.aspx)

Comment: Unfortunately that link doesn't work anymore. Googling didn't help find an alternative link

Answer (score 0):

One solution could be to have a grid where the new fields are displayed as a form and a user can use the same form to add multiple rows of data .Something like a (+) button would do that for you,Just save the previous values of the form when the user asks for a new set of fields.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your database will need to be structured to allow this. i.e. A table to hold the Employee information and another table to hold the employment history. The history table will need to have a foreign key back to the Employee table with a many-to-one relationship.

As for ASP.NET, you need to look up [creating dynamic controls](http://www.google.com/search?q=dynamic%20controls&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&client=firefox-a#sclient=psy-ab&hl=en&safe=off&client=firefox-a&hs=zU9&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&source=hp&q=dynamic%20controls%20.net&pbx=1&oq=dynamic%20controls%20.net&aq=f&aqi=g-e1g3&aql=1&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=2406l3483l0l3525l5l3l0l0l0l0l334l334l3-1l1l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.,cf.osb&fp=4d6e928658d79516&biw=1920&bih=969). You can present a single set of fields with a plus button to add additional ones and then save these in a row of their own in the database.

Answer (score 0):

There is a legacy .NET application where I work, for which most UIs were built using Web Forms.  I recently had request similar to yours for a UI in this application which I achieved using AngularJS.

I give this answer, knowing that it is not the pure Web Forms answer, but it is an solution that can be implemented in your existing Web Form, so I think it is still valid.

Build a controller (Controller, ApiController, or even an .ashx 'Generic Handler') for submitting JSON data that holds all the data applicable to this particular user submission action.  Build the UI components in this Web Form page using pure html and AngularJS (google 'ng-repeat'.  You will see tons of examples that can be applied to your situation). Don't actually use the Web Forms markup this time around.  Your repeatable elements should be bound to data in the front end.  When the user clicks the plus button to add more work history, you add to that data and Angular repeats your desired block.

Hook your submit action for your new html form up to the controller you created (using an ng-submit directive on the form or an ng-click directive on some submit element).  If you know how to work with data and you have followed along so far, you should have it from here.  If you need some more help, I strongly encourage investigating REST APIs and AngularJS.

The sooner you start to learn how to program the front end using more sophisticated tooling than Web Forms, and the sooner you learn how to submit data using pure web technologies (Ajax and JavaScript) then the sooner you will be able to alleviate yourself from the confines of the Web Forms framework.  Don't get me wrong, it does a lot of things awesomely, and helps those who don't know the web, program for the web.  In the end, you will be better off when you at least know how to step outside of its confines when needed.